# OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError Rails 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openssl

I am trying to deploy a rails api on render.com and I get this error message:

```
Mar 15 04:18:01 PM  Installing bootsnap 1.13.0 with native extensions
Mar 15 04:18:11 PM  Bundle complete! 13 Gemfile dependencies, 82 gems now installed.
Mar 15 04:18:11 PM  Gems in the groups 'development' and 'test' were not installed.
Mar 15 04:18:11 PM  Bundled gems are installed into `/opt/render/project/.gems`
Mar 15 04:18:16 PM  rails aborted!
Mar 15 04:18:16 PM  ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage: ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage
Mar 15 04:18:16 PM  /opt/render/project/src/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
Mar 15 04:18:16 PM  
Mar 15 04:18:16 PM  Caused by:
Mar 15 04:18:16 PM  OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError:
Mar 15 04:18:16 PM  /opt/render/project/src/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
Mar 15 04:18:16 PM  Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => db:load_config => environment
Mar 15 04:18:16 PM  (See full trace by running task with --trace)
Mar 15 04:18:17 PM  ==> Build failed 
Mar 15 04:18:17 PM  ==> Generating container image from build. This may take a few minutes...
```

As I am quite new to development(1 year), I don't know how to proceed.I google this error but the solutions given don't apply here.could you help me?

I looked into stackoverflow for that error but, the answers given do not apply for this case.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack overflow. Can you please tell us what you have tried? When you googled it what did it tell you to try and why did that not apply?

Comment: Also, the error is pointing you at this line of code: `/opt/render/project/src/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'` what is in your environment.rb there? (can you paste in the first few lines of that file)?

Comment: Also, have you tried the solution mentioned here: https://collab.codidact.org/posts/285481 which suggests this might come from a corrupted credentials file - and tells you to delete the credentials file and re-create it?